# 404 not found java config spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm doing a small project on `spring MVC`. Spring configuration I am doing on a clean `java` just do not have`xml`. The problem is that it seems like everything was initialized correctly, but the container for some reason does not start and crashes out 404. I'll give you a part of code:

**webconfig.java**

```
import com.myapp.webapp.Interceptors.AccountInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.service",
"com.myapp.webapp"
} )
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/jsp/**").addResourceLocations("/jsp/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    AccountInterceptor accountInterceptor() {
        return new AccountInterceptor();
    }


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(accountInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/account/**");
    }


}
```

**webservletconfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;


public class WebServletConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
            WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebConfig.class
        };
    }
```

And for example **controller**

```
import com.myapp.model.Account;
import com.myapp.model.Phone;
import com.myapp.service.Service;
import com.myapp.webapp.utils.SetAttributes;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



@Controller
@SessionAttributes("accountInSession")
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    Service<Account> accountService;


    @RequestMapping("/join")
    public ModelAndView join(){
        return new ModelAndView("join");
    }

 // there are many more methods
}
```

If I understand correctly, then when I go to `http://localhost:8085/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/account/join` it should be passed to`join.jsp`, which is stored in `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

**main pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>socialnet</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compile.version>3.3</maven.compile.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.194</h2.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.17</mysql.version>
        <dbcp.version>2.1</dbcp.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <maven.deploy.version>2.8.2</maven.deploy.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <tomcat.servler.version>9.0.0.M4</tomcat.servler.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jquery.version>2.1.4</jquery.version>
    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>webapp</module>
    </modules>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compile.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.deploy.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**pom.xml in webapp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>socialnet</artifactId>
        <groupId>myapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.servler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: could you provide your `application.properties` file configuration as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not specified `server.contextPath` in your `application.properties`, you need not be putting the jar/war file name while accessing the application.

Try with `http://localhost:8085/account/join` & let me know if you are still facing any issues.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. All is also an error 404. And now I do my app without spring boot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the war folder name, just use you app name like this:

```
http://localhost: 8085/webapp/account/join
```

If you don't want to use your app name then you need to modify your dispatcher servlet from `/` to `/webapp/` to make your webapp root folder as root directory